# SharePoint Document Library after drag and drop file, status bar does not get closed automatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, drag-and-drop

I have one document library in SharePoint online.

When I drag and drop any file to this library, the status bar does not get closed automatically. However, file uploading is already completed (testFile.txt).

Here. everytime user has to click cancel button to close/hide the status bar.

Please refer below screenshot :

[image]

If Anybody have any idea about this behaviour, please suggest me.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try it in IE?

Comment: @KarthikJaganathan I tries it on IE. But the same issue. And this happes once out of 4-5 times.

Comment: try in chrome and if you get that scenario again, then check in the browser console for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the page.

Add site into trusted site, clear cache and close IE, reopen the site and compare the results.

Does the issue exists in all libraries, try to drag and drop documents in other libraries and compare the results.